this me toma el valor de otra activity en: SQLiteManejo sqLiteC = new SQLiteManejo(this, "movimientos",null, 1);
Estoy desarrollando una app en Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2, con java, usando  una base de datos SQLite; funcionaba bien pero luego marca error en "this" de
SQLiteManejo sqLiteManejo = new SQLiteManejo(this, "movimientos",null, 1);

Me informa que estoy proveyendo el nombre de mi Activity actual y que se requiere el de otra activity

Puedes poner el error exacto? Cuando buscas ayuda técnica es mejor no cambiar el texto de los errores por una abstracción del mismo. Es importante ver el error exacto pues un tecnicismo puede ser la diferencia entre un error u otro.
